# Tag definitions for solar-flare and solar-storm?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

The [solar-storm](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-storm) tag has 8 questions and no usage guidance.

The [solar-flare](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-flare) tag has 32 questions and the following guidance:

> Questions regarding a sudden brightness increase due to the release of magnetic energy from the sun.

which seems *incomplete*.

**Questions:**

1. What would be better usage advice for the [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) tag be?
2. What would usage advice be for the [solar storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_storm) tag be?